# Creating UI dynamically android

Tags: android

I have the following function

```
void callDynamicView(){
        String configText="Building Name, S, 10; No: of Floors, I, 3; Area of Plot, D, 10; Location(X), L, 15.3;  Location(Y),  L, 15.3; Photo, P, 10";

    String[] splits = configText.split(";");    
    for(String splitSemi: splits){

        String[] splitsCommas = splitSemi.split(",");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), splitsCommas[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(splitsCommas[0]);
        ll.addView(tv);
        this.setContentView(sv);

    }



}
```

I am creating textview and UI dynamically here. I need to add `Building Name, No: of floors, Area of Plot, Location(X), Location(Y) and Photo`  as text views. In here It only adding last text field Photo. How can I solve this?

Comment: Move `ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);` outside foreach loop then try

Comment: I have moved the ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this); outside loop. Now its working Thank you bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void callDynamicView(){
    String configText="Building Name, S, 10; No: of Floors, I, 3; Area of Plot, D, 10; Location(X), L, 15.3;  Location(Y),  L, 15.3; Photo, P, 10";
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);
String[] splits = configText.split(";");    
for(String splitSemi: splits){

    String[] splitsCommas = splitSemi.split(",");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), splitsCommas[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(splitsCommas[0]);
    ll.addView(tv);


}
 this.setContentView(sv);


}
```

Try this.